# Best way to grab focus for Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

First off I am kinda new to Android, so with that being said. So I have a spinner, and every time I make a selection the phone will scroll back up to the last edit text who has focus.  That is very annoying so I set the spinner as focusable, but for some reason I then have to click the spinner twice to get it to open (the first click gives the spinner focus, the second opens the spinner). So the best I have come up with so far is this:

```
activitySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.acivity_dropdown);
    activitySpinner.setFocusable(true);
    activitySpinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    activitySpinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            activitySpinner.requestFocus();
            activitySpinner.performClick();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

That takes care of the need for two clicks, but that causes problems because it will open the spinner on the slightest touch, even if all I wanted to do was scroll down. Am I looking at this problem the wrong way? Is there a way to make the spinner focusable and also allow it to open on the first click?

Things I've tried:
Setting focusable in the xml,
setting focusable and focusable in touch mode in java,
the code above

Answer (score 9):

Using `setFocusable(true)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` are correct.  To fix the two-touch problem created by the latter check for the `ACTION_UP` event in your touch handler and return `false` to let the event bubble up which eliminates the extra `requestFocus()` call:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !v.hasFocus()) {
        v.performClick();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `hasFocus()` check makes this specific to the click-twice problem; if the control already has focus, your actual tap should bring up the list without additional work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

```
          spinner.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Comment: I can get focus currently, I'm just having a problem getting the focus without having to click the spinner twice.  Is there a listener I can put that into that would stop me from having the problem I'm having?